# How I encode the ugly string?

Tags: asp.net, unicode

I have a string that is:

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~¡¢£¤¥¦§¨©ª« ®¯°±²³´µ¶•¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâäèçéêëìíîïôö÷òóõùúý
```

I post that to service and used Htmlencode, then I get a result:

```
!#$%&amp;'()* ,-./0123456789:;&lt;=&gt;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~����������� ���������•������������������������������������
```

it isn't result that i need,how i get original string? thanks!

Comment: HTML encoding would of course escape those special characters.  If you don't want it HTML encoded, well, don't HTML encode the string in the first place.

Comment: @Swangren, I believe he means the issue with improper binary encoding.  Perhaps the function he is using is not Unicode safe?  (I don't know ASP.NET so I cannot help.)

Comment: I think he just wants to get the string back into its original form. But the question's not very clear so I could be wrong.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but check the end of the strings. There's a lot missing from the HTML encoded string, which means it wasn't encoded correctly...

Comment: @lc Good point. Tom's suggestion might be best. Encode and decode as Base 64.

Comment: There is something odd about the HtmlEnocded response: things like % shouldn't have survived as literals. I agree that as the data isn't ASCII that encoding it first as base64 may be the best option.

Answer (score 5):

Your string is not ASCII, so you are either using a string to represent binary data, or you're not maintaining awareness of multi-byte encoding.  In any case, the simplest way to deal with any Internet-based technology (HTTP, SMTP, POP, IMAP) is to encode it as 7-bit clean.  One common way is to base64-encode your data, send it across the wire, then base64-decode it before trying to process it.

Comment: Not sure why so many +1 votes here - this answer seems irrelevant to the question, which obviously deals with web programming ("Htmlencode" in addition to the asp.net tag). You cant base64 encode strings to display to users in a web page. (No offense, Tom.) But maybe I'm wrong...

Comment: @wupatah - Yes, you're wrong.  The OP's question is explicitly about posting binary data, not about displaying data to users.  This answer is relevant to how HTTP works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
!&quot;#$%&amp;&apos;()*+,-./0123456789:;?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]\\^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~&iexcl;&cent;&pound;&curren;&yen;&brvbar;&sect;&uml;&copy;&ordf;&laquo;&reg;&macr;&deg;&plusmn;&sup2;&sup3;&acute;&micro;&para;&bull;&cedil;&sup1;&ordm;&raquo;&frac14;&frac12;&frac34;&iquest;&Agrave;&Aacute;&Acirc;&Atilde;&Auml;&Aring;&agrave;&aacute;&acirc;&auml;&egrave;&ccedil;&eacute;&ecirc;&euml;&igrave;&iacute;&icirc;&iuml;&ocirc;&ouml;&divide;&ograve;&oacute;&otilde;&ugrave;&uacute;&yacute;
```

You just need to use a better html entity/encoding library or tool. The one I used to generate this is from Ruby - I used the [HTML Entities library](http://htmlentities.rubyforge.org/). The code I wrote to do this follows. I had to put your text in input.txt to preserve Unicode (there was an EOF character in the string), but it worked great.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'htmlentities'

str = File.read('input.txt')

coder = HTMLEntities.new
puts coder.encode(str, :named)
```